# Why I couldn't catch the error in subflow?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4

From the Main api, i call a subflow. I have defined error handler in the main flow and subflow.(mine is complex scenario)
Here is a simple flow design of what I'm trying;
From the main flow, within Async scope I call i subflow. Mainflow, itself has errorhandler.
Within reporting subflow, i call another subflow, which throws an 403 error.
I thought to handle that in reporting subflow. So i used, on error continue. I used log mediator there to see it gets executed or not.
But it is not.
Rather, from the main flow I get,log ' in main error handler'
I haven't defined any global error handlers.
Why is that?

**Main flow**

```
<flow name="post:\notifications:raml-config">
.................
                <async doc:name="Async">
                    <try doc:name="Try">
                        <flow-ref doc:name="Call-Reporting-subFlow
                            name="reporting-subflow" />
                        <error-handler >
                            <on-error-propagate enableNotifications="true" logException="true" doc:name="On Error Propagate" doc:id="743fc7cb-38d4-4a0c-ab36-9105645ce710" >
                                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="5d18eb33-780e-4353-b65f-b26eec88612a" message="in main errror handler"/>

............
</flow>
```

**Subflow (reporting flow)**

```
<sub-flow name-"reporting-subflow">
<try doc:name="Try"  >
            <flow-ref doc:name="getcontracts"  name="get-details-subflow" />
            <error-handler >
                <on-error-continue enableNotifications="true" logException="true" doc:name="On Error Continue" type="HTTP:FORBIDDEN">
                        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="GOT 403 error"/>
                <flow-ref doc:name="gettoken"  name="getToken-subflow" />
</error-handler>
        </try>
</sub-flow>
```

Comment: Have you validated that you are indeed getting an "HTTP:FORBIDDEN" error? Cause your subflow error handler is only accepting that type of error, while the async one is accepting all errors.

Comment: @afelisatti yes, it is 403.  failed: forbidden (403).
Error type            : HTTP:FORBIDDEN

Comment: @afelisatti I changed the reporting subflow to flow, now my try scope's error handling catch the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the below may be the reason:

1. We cannot define an error handling for a sub flow, we can do it only
   for private flows and normal flows.
2. Even if the main flow has an error handler, the flow referred within
   the Async scope will not be managed by this error handler. To solve
   this:

   - make the flow referenced within the async error handler as a
     private flow and define a error handling at flow level
   - or define global error handling at application level.